# Populate jqgrid with only selected xml data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jqgrid

I have a form which takes an id as input and based on the existence of this id in an xml file it has to populate a jqgrid table with related info from the same xml file. Please help. My xml code looks like

```
<EmpDetails>
  <Detail detailid="1">
    <empid>12345</empid>
    <Transaction transid="11">
      <date>09-01-2015</date>
      <type>Credit</type>
      <amount>15000</amount>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction transid="12">
      <date>09-02-2015</date>
      <type>Debit</type>
      <amount>200</amount>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction transid="13">
      <date>09-03-2015</date>
      <type>Debit</type>
    </Transaction>
  </Detail>
  <Detail detailid="2">
    <empid>67890</empid>
    <Transaction transid="21">
      <date>09-02-2015</date>
      <type>Debit</type>
      <amount>1200</amount>
    </Transaction>
   </Detail>
</EmpDetails>
```

and the javascript code is

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#button1').click(function () {

            var textname = $('#name').val();
            var textempid = $('#empid').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "DataScripts/Data1.xml",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    $(xml).find('Detail').each(function () {
                        var empid = $(this).find("empid").text();
                        var detailid = $(this).attr('detailid');

                        if (textempid==empid)
                        {
                            populategrid(detailid);
                        }

                    });
                }
            });

  function populategrid(detailid)
        {
           $('#GridTable').jqGrid({

                url: 'DataScripts/Data1.xml',
                datatype: "xml",
                colModel: [
                    {label: 'date', name: 'date', key: false, width: 75, xmlmap: 'date'},
                    {label: 'type', name: 'type', sortable: true, xmlmap: 'type'},
                    {label: 'amount', name: 'amount', sortable: true, xmlmap: 'amount'} 
                ],
                xmlReader: {
                    root: "EmpDetails",
                    row: "Detail>Transaction",
                    repeatitems: false,
                    id: "[detailid]"
                },
                width: 780,
                height: 250,
                rowNum: 5,
                pager: "#jqGridPager",
            }).navGrid('#jqGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false }); 
           return;
      }
```

When I execute this, I see transaction details of the other empid along with entered empid's transaction info are also displayed on the grid.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You use `textname == name && textempid==empid` to search for specific `"name"` and `"empid"` nodes of `<Detail>`, but I don't see any `name` node (only `empid`) inside of any `<Detail>`. Let us you have found some `<Detail>` node then it's unclear for me why you don't forward the node to the `populategrid` to allow jqGrid to read only `Transaction` of **the specific** (found) node? You could use `datastr: detailNade, datatype: "xmlstring"` options of jqGrid. If the information is not enough for you then I could post more implementation details.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg. Please ignore (textname==name). I have edited my code now. I only validate with empid. Can you please post more details on how to forward detail node to grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to implement your requirements, but the most easy way seems to me to use `xmlReader` with `row` defined as function. Inside of the function one can filter `<Detail>` elements to find only the elements which have specific `<empid>` sub-element. Such way makes unneeded the usage of additional separate `$.ajax` call.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/samina.htm) displays the following results

[image]

It uses the following code

```js
$("#GridTable").jqGrid({
    url: "samina.xml",
    datatype: "xml",
    colModel: [
        {name: "date", width: 75},
        {name: "type"},
        {name: "amount", formatter: "integer", sorttype: "integer"}
    ],
    xmlReader: {
        root: "EmpDetails",
        row: function (obj) {
            var empid = $("#empid").val(),
                // get Detail with specific empid element
                details = $(obj).children("Detail").filter(function () {
                    if ($(this).children("empid").text() === empid) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            return $(details).children("Transaction");
        },
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "[transid]"
    },
    width: 780,
    height: "auto",
    rowNum: 5,
    loadonce: true,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    pager: "#jqGridPager"
}).jqGrid("navGrid", "#jqGridPager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false, hideEmptyPagerParts: false });
```

The most important above is the `row` and `id` part of `xmlReader` which I changed.

Comment: Thank you so much Oleg. It worked perfectly.Also can you please explain what is the significance of "rows=[]" here. Thanks

Comment: @samina: You are welcome! You can of cause remove unneeded `rows=[]`. I wanted first to push `<Detail>` elements, which has specific `empid` element, in `rows` array, but then decided to use `jQuery.filter` instead. I updated the code from the answer.